# Python's scipy.sparse.csr_matrix to Matlab conversion

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

Im trying to convert a code from python to matlab.

```
m, n = np.shape(M) % M is my data
k=10;

r = k * 5
C = np.arange(n)
R = np.random.random_integers(r, size=n) - 1
D = np.random.randint(2, size=n) * 2 - 1
S = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((D, (R, C)), shape=(r, n))
```

How do i write the S variable in matlab? is there an equivalent function?

Comment: You can't change the question to ask another question! If it's resolved, you will need to ask another question, in a separate post.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `csr_matrix`, [`sparse` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) can be useful:

> `S = sparse(i,j,v)` generates a sparse matrix S from the triplets `i`, `j`, and `v` such that `S(i(k),j(k)) = v(k)`. The max(i)-by-max(j) output matrix has space allotted for `length(v)` nonzero elements.
> If the inputs `i`, `j`, and `v` are vectors or matrices, they must have the same number of elements. Alternatively, the argument `v` and/or one of the arguments `i` or `j` can be scalars.

> `S = sparse(i,j,v,m,n)` specifies the size of `S` as m-by-n.

Comment: I tried it. it seems to work but what if i want to have 2 different S matrix. Given an original matrix M (m-by-n)  I wish to find a) S1 will be a nu-by-m and b) S2 will be n-by-nu. Im not sure how to deal with the i j v. since i dont want to use the same when finding both S1 and S2. any ideas?